# How to configure Wordpress to be a subdirectory of my main site as mymainsite.com/blog?

Tags: permalinks

I have developed a site www.mainsite.com based on Ruby on Rails hosted on Heroku. I have also developed a blogging site based on Wordpress at blog.mainsite.com hosted on Dreamhost. I want our users to interact with www.mainsite.com/blog instead of blog.mainsite.com.
I have each site function correctly, and the DNS setup correctly. I also set up reverse proxy in Rails to route traffic
reverse_proxy /^/blog(/.*)$/, 'http://blog.mainsite.com$1', opts={:preserve_host => true}

Most of the time it work.
After I messed with the permalinks and restored it, now in Wordpress, whenever I upload a media file (image), it always sends me to www.mainsite.com/wp-admin (404) instead of www.mainsite.com/blog/wp-admin.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On the admin panel, under Settings -> General Settings, make sure the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" are correct. Also, check out the [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).